# Printing one to many relationship in c#

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am unable to access a one to many relationship, when I create it it works, but when I try to print it, it gives me an error " System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' " This is how it is setup:

```
public class Question
{
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}

public class ApprovalRatingContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Question> Questions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Answer> Answers { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=TrumpGame;Trusted_Connection=True;");
    }
}
```

This is the many class:

```
public class Answer
{
    public int AnswerId { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string ApprovalRating { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }

    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
}
```

And this is how im trying to access it:

```
ApprovalRatingContext questionContext = new ApprovalRatingContext();
foreach (var question in questionContext.Questions)
{
    Console.WriteLine(question.Content);

    List<Answer> answers = question.Answers;

    foreach (Answer answer in answers)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(answer.Amount);
    }

}

Console.ReadLine();
```

This is a console application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you query data from *Entity Framework Core*, it doesn't load related entities automatically. So `questionContext.Questions` loads all questions from database, but related `Answer`s are NOT loaded. Therefore `question.Answers` is null and throws `NullReferenceException` when accessed.

To fix it, you need to ensure that `Answer`s are loaded too. *EF Core* has extension method `Include` for this purpose. You just need to append `.Include(q => q.Answers)` to your query like this:

```
foreach (var question in questionContext.Questions.Include(q => q.Answers))
{
    // ...
}
```

Alternatively, you can use *lazy-loading* to load data automatically on-demand. See
[Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data)